# Can you shortcut wine apps to steam?

Tags: steam

As the tile says.

I would just try this myself but I don't currently have a distro of Linux running right now. Basically I would like to know if can shortcut a windows game or app that you have installed via wine so that it shows up in your steam library right along side your proper steam games.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm confused, what does wine have to do with steam?  Are you asking if you can run games not supported in Linux through Wine and have them appear in your steam games list?

Comment: Can you explain your issue properly? it is bit difficult to understand.

Comment: See this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/324060/mixed-mode-in-steam-wine-native?rq=1

Comment: Sorry about that. I am asking if you can make a steam shortcut like you would with any non steam game or app. I've only used steam on windows so perhaps I'm confused about something. I am asking if you can shortcut a windows game/app that you have installed via wine to steam so that it shows up in your steam library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mixed mode in Steam (wine/native)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324060/mixed-mode-in-steam-wine-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
https://github.com/ValveSoftware/SteamOS/wiki/Working-with-non-Steam-games
This guide shows you how to do it. To get Windows games to work, simply make a .desktop file and in the exec line, put Wine with all your arguments and the path to the game and it should work just as if you were running it from the terminal.